# How to learn node.js in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I am new and want to learn node.js for web development and data science results.
I am using Eclipse oxygen and have installed nodeclipse from market place.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Please provide and MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My question is not code oriented it is general question.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter what text editor you use as long as the file is a JavaScript file. All you have to do to run your code is navigate to the directory where your file exists and run  `node file-name.js` from your terminal.